# Prevent rerendering of custom Control

Tags: javascript, sapui5

For our openUI5 application I have developed two custom controls. One utilizing the gridstack.js library and another using the HighCharts library.
The former has the latter as aggregation 'charts' (1...n).
When I update the property in the model(deleting, adding a chart), the wrapper control re renders the charts (default behavior).

Is there a way to prevent re-rendering of the aggregation, because it causes both libraries to reload some stuff and this behavior we must avoid.

I thought about calling validate() on the charts aggregation as well as overwriting the setAggregation in the wrapper control.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use [`sap.ui.core.HTML`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.HTML);
This control was meant for this scenario, its property `preferDOM` does exactly that. So instead of rendering the HTML of the libraries I'm using, I set it as `content` of the `sap.ui.core.HTML` control.